# skip-grant-tables,skip-networking

Tags: mysql, mysql-5.6, linux

What happens if we put `skip-grant-tables`, `skip-networking` these two options in `my.cnf` file and restarted the server in production hours, will there be any loss of data. I removed them immediately and resarted the server and brought it to normal. Can anyone explain the consequences please?

Comment: I think it will allow logins to the MySQL instance without a password and it also disabled TCP/IP entirely so it's only accessible via the localhost. I think that's what the consequences would be; MySQL instance not accessible remotely and you can log into the instance of the MySQL locally without a password.